# Mongoid embeds_many with default order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

How can I set default order to my embeded objects, like:

```
class Post
  embeds_many :comments, :order => "author"
  accepts_nested_attributes_for
end
```

Now I handle it with passing order straight:

```
f.fields_for :comments, @post.comments.asc(:author) do |comment|
  ...
end
```

Comment: Which version of mongoid you are using? https://github.com/mongoid/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/relations/embedded/many.rb#L495 you can see, embeds_many accepts an option `:order` from 2.1.0

Comment: @Rubish Gupta, wow! I am on `2.0.2`! But no effect on `2.1.7` :(

Comment: or may be it also accepts it in 2.0.2, because checking validation code to options was added recently in mongoid. So, perhaps 2.1.0 just added a method which returns valid options. You should try using `:order` if you haven't already before considering an upgrade.

Comment: @Rubish Gupta, actually there is no any `order` method. There is `asc`, `order_by` and `desc` methods

Comment: There is a method order `User.all.order([:college_id, Mongo::ASCENDING]).limit(10).count(true)` works fine on my system(2.0.1)

Comment: Perhaps you need to change `:order => "author"` to `:order => [:author, Mongo::ASCENDING]`

Comment: @Rubish Gupta, no effect. I can order it in console, but it didn't work in assosiation as default. (and `order` looks like alias to `order_by`)

Comment: I also tried it in console and using the option, but it hasn't any effect.

Comment: you might want to have a look at http://groups.google.com/group/mongoid/browse_thread/thread/a510a52a833ef1d6

Answer (score 8):

In mongoid 3.1.2 you can do something like this:

```
embeds_many :favorites, order: :title.desc
```

It also works with `:title.asc`

Comment: This still stands true in Mongoid 5.1